# Tabs Ajax reponses load in wrong pane

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem with Ajax request in tabs. Content of tabs are loading via Ajax request. if user clicks and explores on tabs fast and before the Ajax response of previous clicked tab received, the content loads in wrong tab pane not in its pane.

It seems the tb_paneID for each ajax request is changed when success of request runs.

Here is the code:

```
 $(".nav-tabs [data-url]").on('click', function() {
    tb_loadUrl = $(this).data('url');
    tb_paneID = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
         url: tb_loadUrl, 
         success: function(data) {
            $(tb_paneID).html(data);
         }
    });

 });
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can we please see the HTML too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using global variables that's why whenever a new click event is triggered before the previous ajax call has been finished, the `tb_panelID` will be updated. Try this

```
$(".nav-tabs [data-url]").on('click', function() {
    var tb_loadUrl = $(this).data('url');
    var tb_paneID = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
         url: tb_loadUrl, 
         success: function(data) {
            $(tb_paneID).html(data);
         }
    });

 });
```